# What does "color cell" mean?

Tags: emacs, colors, elisp

I saw a term "color cell" in the [Emacs Lisp Reference Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Display-Feature-Testing.html#Display-Feature-Testing):

> — Function: display-color-cells &optional display
>
> This function returns the number of color cells the screen supports.

What does it mean?  I searched it but didn't get anything that looked promising.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It returns the number of colors that the display can render.

For example. My display support 8 bits for each of the three colors Red, Green, and Blue. Hence, it can represent 2^8*2^8*2^8 = 256*256*256 = 16777216 colors, which is the return value of `display-color-cells`.